# AngularJS multi select checkboxes saves in comma separated String

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multi-select

I want to get comma separated string from selected check-box items in angularJS.  At the same time, when comma separated string is retrived from database, I want check-boxes to be checked accordingly.

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Drawings.CarMDrawings" ng-change="Update(Drawings)"> Car
    <br />

    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Drawings.SignalMDrawings" ng-change="Update(Drawings)"> Signal
    <br />

    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Drawings.DoorMDawings" ng-change="Update(Drawings)"> Door
    <br />

  </div>
```

I have solved the problem in very simplistic way is Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/YYd5bN5Chmyjt6gSH1Bw?p=preview

```
 $scope.Update = function(Drawings) {
    var str = "";
    if (Drawings.CarMDrawings) {
      str = "Car";
    }
    if (Drawings.SignalMDrawings) {
      str = str + ",Signal";
    }
    if (Drawings.DoorMDawings) {
      str = str + ",Door";
    }
    if (str.charAt(0) === ',') {
      str = str.substr(1);
    }
    $scope.data = str;
  }

  $scope.revUpdate = function(data) {
    var str = data;
    $scope.Drawings = {};
    if (str.indexOf('Car') != -1) {

      $scope.Drawings.CarMDrawings = true;
    }
    if (str.indexOf('Signal') != -1) {

      $scope.Drawings.SignalMDrawings = true;
    }
    if (str.indexOf('Door') != -1) {

      $scope.Drawings.DoorMDawings = true;
    }
```

}

But it is not helpful when I have many similar items. Could any one help me building a directive or extension so that I could reuse them frequently. 
P.S. I don't want array of objects but simple comma separated string items.

Answer (score 0):

If you use 'indexOf', you'll get many garbage items those include text what you want to find.

So I think this is the most nearest way to get more precise value.

```
if (new RegExp("\\b"+"Car"+"\\b").test(str)) {
    $scope.Drawings.CarMDrawings = true;
}

var str="test ,Car ,test";  //true
var str="test, Car, test";  //true
var str="test Cartest";     //false
var str="testCar test";     //false
```

Maybe this is very late answer but I hope this is right for your intent,

and helpful for other people who'll look this. :)